# Keep ratio image on scale up or down without object fit

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where I need to scale up or scale down an image inside a div based on viewport width and height.

I can achieve what I want using `object-fit: contain;` property.

But with this property, the width or height of the image in the DOM are not the real value when I get it from javascript. 
I want the real width and height because I need to calculate the position of element inside the image.

Here is what I have done so far :

```
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   position: relative;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   width: calc(76vw - 60px);
   height: calc(100vh - 100px);
   margin: 30px 0px 30px 30px;
}
.img {
   width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   object-fit: contain;
   height: 100%;
}
```

This is the expected result visually, but not the expected value.

Here is a fiddle, when you change window width, height of image change but not his value.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrkvg6xy/10/)

Comment: Is the image aspect ratio known?

Comment: @Stickers I have the possibility to fix the image ratio but for more flexibility it will be better that this works with any ratio, this is why it's a bit tricky

Comment: What does it mean "calculate the position of element inside the image"?

Comment: @Stickers There is a drag and drop inside the image, I need to create a wrapper div for the elements that will be dragged so this div should be the same size as the image

Comment: Well, since you'll be using js, you can probably do it all with js.